# compatability with 2.3 and higher with listfragments, tabhost,simple curson adapter

Tags: listview, android-listview, android-asynctask, android-tabhost, android-2.3-gingerbread

I am creating app to load tweets for a particular firm. To make it compatible with Android 2.3 and higher version, i needed to use FragmentActivity & ListFragment. I am getting tweets on app start in FragmentAcitivity class using AsyncTask and adding tabs and also loading them in the sqlite DB. Now, on tab click I need to load those tweets from the sqllite DB for which I am using LoaderManager but nothing is displaying on tab click. here is my code snippet :

FragmentActivity:

```
     @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tag) {  
Log.d(TAG, "onTabChanged");  
TabInfo newTab = this.mapTabInfo.get(tag);  
if (mLastTab != newTab) {  
  FragmentTransaction ft = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();  
if (mLastTab != null) {  
if (mLastTab.fragment != null) {  
 ft.detach(mLastTab.fragment);  
 }  
}  
if (newTab != null) {  
if (newTab.fragment == null) {  
newTab.fragment = (ListFragment) ListFragment.instantiate(this, newTab.clss.getName(), newTab.args);  
ft.add(R.id.realtabcontent, newTab.fragment, newTab.tag);  
} else {ft.attach(newTab.fragment);  
}  
}     
mLastTab = newTab;  
ft.commit();  
this.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();  
}    
}
```

ListFragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView");  
if (container == null) {  
return null;  
}   
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, null,TweetStatusProvider.FROM,TweetStatusProvider.TO,CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);  
adapter.setViewBinder(VIEW_BINDER);  
getLoaderManager().initLoader(STATUS_LOADER, null, this);  
Log.d(TAG, "initLoader executed");  
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment_layout, container, false);      
ListView listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);  
listView.setAdapter(adapter);  
return view;  
}
```

Layout:
main.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
 '<'TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
  android:id="@android:id/tabhost"  
  android:layout_width="match_parent"  
  android:layout_height="match_parent" '>'  
'<'LinearLayout  
android:layout_width="match_parent"  
android:layout_height="match_parent"  
android:background="@drawable/background"  
android:orientation="vertical"  
android:padding="10dp" '>'  
'<'HorizontalScrollView  
android:layout_width="match_parent"  
android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
android:scrollbars="none" '>'  
'<'TabWidget  
android:id="@android:id/tabs"  
android:layout_width="54dp"  
android:layout_height="60dp" '/>'  

'<'/HorizontalScrollView'>'  
'<'FrameLayout  
android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"  
android:layout_width="match_parent"  
android:layout_height="match_parent"  
android:padding="5dp" '>'  
'<'/FrameLayout'>'  
'<'FrameLayout  
android:id="@+android:id/realtabcontent"  
android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
android:layout_height="0dp"  
android:layout_weight="1" /'>'  
'<'/LinearLayout'>'  
'<'/TabHost'>'
```

list_fragment_layout.xml:

```
 '<'?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?'>'  
 '<'LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     
 android:layout_width="match_parent"    
 android:layout_height="match_parent"    
 android:orientation="vertical" '>'    

 '<'ListView  
 android:id="@android:id/list"  
 android:layout_width="match_parent"  
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" '>'  
 '<'/ListView'>'    
'<'/LinearLayout'>'
```

row.xml:

```
'<'?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?'>'  
'<'RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="match_parent" '>'  
    '<'TextView  
 android:id="@+id/text_user"  
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"  
 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"  
 android:text="Large Text"  
 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" /'>'  

'<'TextView  
 android:id="@+id/text_created_at"  
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"  
 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"  
 android:text="10 minutes ago"  
 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" /'>'  
'<'TextView  
  android:id="@+id/text_text"  
  android:autoLink="all"  
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"  
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"  
  android:layout_below="@+id/text_user"  
  android:text="Small Text"  
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" /'>'  
'<'/RelativeLayout'>'
```

Comment: Just FYI, that is an *awful* lot of information. If you remove the non-essential code, you'll be much more likely to get an answer quickly.

Comment: I am not sure which part of code is creating problem, so I added lost of info here. Tabs are coming in 2.3 but nothing happening on click on them

Comment: Can anyone please suggest something here ?

Comment: still waiting for some solution ?

Comment: Dude, it's like I said. No one is going to climb through your entire project and debug it for you. Put some time in and try to isolate the issue. Then people will be more interested in helping you find the solution.